# Techniques for Stopping a Diagnostic Study for Safety

Tags: clinical-trials, sequential-analysis

I'm working with a group of physicians who are interested in evaluating a new diagnostic tool for detecting colon cancer in older patients.  The gold standard to detect colon cancer is with a colonoscopy (hereafter "a scope").  Their plan is to administer the diagnostic and then scope all patients so as to calculate things like positive predictive value, sensitivity, etc.

The scope is invasive and carries risk of adverse events, especially in the study population.  Hence, the physicians want to limit the number of true negatives receiving the scope.  Because there is no way to determine a priori who is a true negative, I thought an interim analysis would suffice.  Broadly, we will pre-specify sample sizes of diagnostic negative patients.  At each pre-specified sample size, we will compute a non-inferiority test for the NPV.  If at any point it becomes unlikely we will reject the null of the non-inferiority test then we will stop the study for safety.

#### Question

If this procedure sounds reasonable for avoiding scoping patients unnecessarily, how can I determine a stopping rule which preserves the false positive rate?  How can I determine the number of individuals needed to power the study effectively, especially given the fact we don't know how many individuals will test negative?